# UART communication with a Thorlabs chip

Tags: microcontroller, integrated-circuit, uart, driver, rs232

I am trying to configure a Thorlabs temperature driver (MTD415TE), using a UART-USB connection. For this, I am using a Foca v2.2 with a FT232R USB-UART cable. I am using serial terminals such as Termite, XCTU, and RealTerm. I have obtained a partial connection with the chip: when I turn it on, it automatically sends the configuration information to the terminal, as can be seen here: [image]

The problem begins when I start sending information: either the chip doesnt respond at all, or says "unkown command" some times.

I listed some possible problems:

- Termite serial terminal is supposed to work with RS232, not with FT232R USB- 
  UART cables. I doubt this is the problem since the program receives the data 
  without problem.
- No information about XCTU and FT232R. I suppose it works with FT232R too.
- Wrong input of commands. For example, "m?" is supposed to be a command. 
  Datasheet says: Command /response Terminator: Line Feed ()
  I already tried multiple combinations such as: "m?", "m?", "m?". None 
  seem to work. The datasheet can be read here: 
  https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/70589858588c8cf-53F8C637-D3AC-D6EE-30854FA37155D43F/MTD415TE-DataSheet.pdf

Thank you

Comment: I don't know anything about your device, but make sure your Append options in the Settings menu are right.  It sounds like you need to append a line feed, and not the nothing option.

Comment: Thank you. It seems that "Appending LF" makes it work, though I have to remove the commas from the command.